# How to get the value of the dropdown menu as a SQL query in php file and Display the query result on table?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, drop-down-menu

i have a table that contains all the records of my db but i want to filter it using 2 dropdown list. like i have 4 columns on my table ID, Name, Subject and Section iwant to filter the results using a dropdown list for Subject and Section

those 2 dropdown list are connected to db section_ubject, and i use php - sql to populate the dropdown list

next is i have a filter button, if i click on it the table records will be filtered according to the selected dropdown record.

the thing is i dont know how to run the query on the other php file where i declare the query as a function.

```
function AllList() {
    $qry = "SELECT * 
        FROM student_subject WHERE SUBJECT = DROPDOWN1 AND SECTION = DROPDOWN2
        ORDER BY `Section` DESC,Name ASC";
        return $this->select($qry);
}
```

i just dont know how will i get the value of those dropdown lists :(

hope somebody would help me :( thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jquery ajax to get values of dropdowns and send them to php script. For example;

```
    <select name="dropdown1">
    <option>Value 1</option>
    <option>Value 2</option>
    <option>Value 3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="dropdown2">
    <option>Value 4</option>
    <option>Value 5</option>
    <option>Value 6</option>
    </select>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="filter_btn">Filter</a>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $("a#filter_btn").click(function(){
            var dropdown1 = $("select[name=dropdown1] :selected").val();
            var dropdown2 = $("select[name=dropdown2] :selected").val();    

            if(dropdown1 != '' && dropdown2 != ''){
                $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "filter.php",
                data : "dropdown1="+dropdown1+"&dropdown2="+dropdown2,
                    success: function(response){
                        alert(response);
                    }
                  });
              }
           });
       });
       </script>

 and in php you can get them like;
        <?php
        $drop1 = $_POST["dropdown1"];
        $drop2 = $_POST["dropdown2"];
        ?>
```

Comment: thank you sir but how bout if my dropdownlist are populated from the data from db sample this is my dropdownlist1 '<?php
$query1 = "SELECT Subuject FROM subject_section";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
$dropdown1 = "<select name='Subject' id='Subject'>";
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
  $dropdown1 .= "\r\n<option value='{$row1['Subuject']}'>{$row1['Subuject']}</option>";
}
$dropdown1 .= "\r\n</select>";
echo $dropdown1;
?>'